# fancybox is not centered

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I am using fancybox 1.3.4 to show some content in popup, but the popup is not centered in browser how to fix it?

html code:

```
<a class="clickMe" title="" message="Last Updated: 10/1/2013">Privacy Policy</a>
```

js code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".clickMe", function(){
    showAlertSized($(this).attr("title"), $(this).attr("message"), $(this).attr("width"), $(this).attr("height"));
});
function showAlertSized(title, msg, width, height) {
    debugger;
    if(width === undefined){
        //width = 965;
        width = '95%';
    }
    if(height === undefined) {
        //height = 700;
        height = '95%';
    }
    var content = '<h1>' + title + '</h1>' +
        '<p class="msg">' + msg + '</p>' +
        '<div class="fancy-btns"><input type="button" value="" onclick="closeAlert()" class="fancy-ok-btn" /></div>';
    $.fancybox({
        'content': content,
        'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
        'overlayOpacity' : 0.7,
        'overlayColor' : '#777',
        'width': width,
        'height': height,
        'autoDimensions': false,
        'autoSize': false
    });
}
```

here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: what is your question? all we see here is a bunch of code and a screenshot...

Comment: see the title of question

Answer (score 0):

your width and height are set to 95% of the viewport so by logic you have 5% width and height unaccounted for. Try adding 'margin': 2.5% to your fancybox initialisation call, this should put a 2.5% margin on all 4 sides of your fancybox, making it perfectly centered. Unfortunately I am unable to test this or provide a coded example, but theoretically it should work!